# QGIS Server: how to get WMS GetLegendGraphic in HTML?

Tags: qgis, legend, html, qgis-server, getlegendgraphic

On MapServer you can get HTML content based legend graphic with WMS GetLegendGraphic.

On QGIS we can have only PNGs.

It would be nice to have the same behaviour on QGIS Server, with an HTML Template like in MapServer. The documentation reference is here: http://mapserver.org/output/html_legend.html

Comment: As currently phrased, I'm not sure if this is a question that can be answered here; it appears to be an enhancement request for the QGIS server developers that should probably go here: http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

Comment: Yes, but I would like to know if someone has solved this issue in any manner

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question, for example if you know that _On QGIS we can have only PNGs._  how can there be an answer about using HTML?  Perhaps you mean through the standard interface there appears to be no way of configuring an HTML response...